# Getting Signal Strength in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity, signals, android-context

I am coding in the sample watch face and I used this guide:
http://www.firstdroid.com/2010/05/12/get-provider-gsm-signal-strength/

I created two separate classes exactly like there except that instead of using R.layout.main in the GetGsmSignalStrength Class, I used R.layout.activity_digital_config, and also instead of doing Toast.makeText() in the listener class which works alongside it, I'm using Log.v(). Finally, I'm trying to call the whole thing inside of my AnalogWatchFaceService OnCreateMethod by creating a GetGsmSignalStrength like so:

```
GetGsmSignalStrength signal = new GetGsmSignalStrength();
```

I'm just inferring on what I'm supposed to do in my case, and I'm probably wrong. I didn't see anything printing out. How can I get it to work? Thanks.

The code that I'm using is in the guide. My class where I'm executing is like this:

```
public class AnalogWatchFaceService extends CanvasWatchFaceService  { 
private static final String TAG = "AnalogWatchFaceService";

@Override
public Engine onCreateEngine() {
    return new Engine();
}

private class Engine extends CanvasWatchFaceService.Engine {
```

Comment: It is quite difficult to assist you without seeing the code

Comment: I edited the post with info on that

Comment: I don't see any code that uses `GetGsmSignalStrength()` or tries to print out any values.

Comment: onCreate() is supposedly called on instantiation. So I tried doing onResume() and received NullPointException for resuming a null activity.